# How to draw a JButton in Android

Tags: java, android, button

Which class should I use in an Android program so that when it gets 1 it draws a button or textfield, when it gets 0 it does not draw anything. There is a class in Java that can perform this functionality? I want that when I get 1 it shoud draw button.

Comment: hmmm that isn't clear for me what did you means with `draw`, could you be little bit concrete...

Comment: i mean to add on frame...not draw through paintcomponent..

Comment: If you could read some documents on Android, you would know, that Android does not support Swing APIs, Android has its own set of widgets, that you should use to draw UI components.

Answer (score 3):

Android doesn't use JButtons, it uses it's own Button widget: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 0):

Both JButton and JTextArea etc, etc extend JComponent. To draw any JComponent you need JContainer. There are a lot: JPanel, JFrame etc.

So in simple case just create your container, your component and add component to container.

```
void foo(int i) {
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setSize(200, 200);
if (i == 1) {
    f.add(new JButton("aaaaa"));
} else if (i == 2) {
    f.add(new JTextField());
}
}
```

Comment: if i call foo(1),then foo(2)..then it is creating two frames....i just want a single window

Comment: @john Of course it's creating two frames, because the JFrame will be initialized every time you call the method

Comment: sir i am creating an android app,i just want a single window.

Comment: @NelttjeN, you really should have submitted [your edit suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/75578) as a new answer, instead. While anyone is allowed to edit everything, it is best to not drastically change the meaning of someone's question or answer.